# Default Filename in Save File Dialog with OPENFILENAMEA Class in C++

Tags: c++, windows, unreal-engine4, savefiledialog

I'm creating a Windows application in C++ (actually, C++ coding in Unreal Engine 4 being packaged for Windows) that allows the user to save a file to their desktop. I am using the `OPENFILENAMEA` structure to handle this (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamea)). I am wanting to set the default filename that appears in the dialog box, but nothing I have tried works.

Specifically, I'm wanting there to be a default value set here, such as "MySavedFile.txt":

[image: Example Picture]

Is it possible to set the default filename for the file to be saved as when using the `OPENFILENAMEA` structure? If so, can you provide an example? I've been unable to figure it out so far and an example would really help.

Comment: Note that `GetSaveFileName()` has been deprecated since Windows Vista.  Use [`IFileSaveDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifilesavedialog) instead, which has a [`SetFileName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog-setfilename) method: “*Sets the file name that appears in the File name edit box when that dialog box is opened.*”

Answer (score 1):

The initial filename is set through `lpstrFile` in [`OPENFILENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamea), following is a minimal example.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    OPENFILENAME ofn = { sizeof(OPENFILENAME) };

    char szFile[_MAX_PATH] = "name";
    const char szExt[] = "ext\0"; // extra '\0' for lpstrFilter

    ofn.hwndOwner = GetConsoleWindow();
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFile; // <--------------------- initial file name
    ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile) / sizeof(szFile[0]);
    ofn.lpstrFilter = ofn.lpstrDefExt = szExt;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_SHOWHELP | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT;

    if (GetSaveFileName(&ofn))
    {
        printf("save-as  '%s'\n", ofn.lpstrFile);
        printf("filename '%s'\n", ofn.lpstrFile + ofn.nFileOffset);
    }
}
```

Comment: What would this look like using OPENFILENAMEW? OPENFILENAMEA does not work with unicode characters, which I need to use, but I couldn't figure out how to get OPENFILENAMEW to have an initial file name in the bar. It seems like it has to be done differently than for OPENFILENAMEA.

Comment: @Spishbert The question was about OPENFILENAMEA specifically, which is why the answer assumed an `A` ANSI build. For the Unicode `W` version of it, just replace `char` with `wchar_t` (or the `WCHAR` typedef) and prefix string literals with `L` for "wide", for example `WCHAR wszFile[_MAX_PATH] = L"name";`. Or, to compile for either ANSI or Unicode depending on the `UNICODE`, `_UNICODE` macros use `TCHAR tszFile[_MAX_PATH] = TEXT("name");` as described in [Working with Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings).